# Boost 1.52.0 Cannot find lexical_cast.hpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

I am using Visual Studio 2010.  I try to utilize the "[C++ String Toolkit Library](http://www.partow.net/programming/strtk/index.html)".  It cannot find "lexical_cast" folder or "lexical_cast.hpp", in the boost folder.  Any work around solution?  Is it just for Linux?

Comment: Can you find those two files on the system? If so, you may need to check whether the path to those files are correct

Comment: Did a search in my computer, but it can't find it.

Comment: Consider reinstalling BOOST library.